# how can i choose multiple chains as a structure object for structural alignment in biojava

Tags: java, biojava

I am trying to do a structural alignment using BioJava libraries. I want to pick some chains from one structure object one by one and add them to another structure object so I can do structural alignment with them but I couldn't yet figure out how. The code I wrote so far is below, but it gives null pointer exception (probably because `new_structure` is set to null). What else can I try?

```
 private static Structure prepareStructures(String structure_name, AtomCache cache){

    Structure structure = null;
    Structure new_structure = null;
    String[] pdbnchain;
    try{
        pdbnchain = structure_name.split("\\.");
        structure = cache.getStructure(pdbnchain[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < pdbnchain[1].length(); i++){
            String letter = pdbnchain[1].charAt(i)+"";
            new_structure.addChain(structure.getChainByPDB(letter));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new_structure;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

```
Structure new_structure = structure.clone();
```

to get an identical copy of the structure.Then you will be having all chains of first structure in the new_structure too.

probably you should do that after:

```
structure = cache.getStructure(pdbnchain[0]);
new_structure = structure.clone();
```

to have a non null value. 
Please refer to [this](http://www.biojava.org/docs/api/org/biojava/bio/structure/class-use/Structure.html) documentation.

You can also try:

```
Structure new_structure = new StructureImpl(); // StructureImpl implements Structure interface.
```

Comment: But I don't want to have all the chains, that's the problem. I want to have some of the chains.